# XAML align text in different stackpanels

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I'm not sure if what i want is even possible, but here we go. I have multiple stackpanels with multiple lines in them As shown in the following code:

```
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="700,75,0,0">
            <Border>
                <TextBlock OpticalMarginAlignment="None">
                    <Run FontSize="24" Text="Product"></Run><LineBreak/>
                    <Run FontSize="18" Text="Artikelnummer: "></Run><Run FontSize="18" Text="{Binding ItemNo}"></Run><LineBreak/>
                    <Run FontSize="18" Text="Omschrijving: "></Run><Run FontSize="18" Text="{Binding Description}"></Run>
                </TextBlock>
            </Border>
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="700,175,0,0">
            <Border>
                <TextBlock OpticalMarginAlignment="None">
                    <Run FontSize="24" Text="Prijzen"></Run><LineBreak/>
                    <Run FontSize="18" Text="Inkoop prijs: "></Run><Run FontSize="18" Text="{Binding PurchasePrice}"></Run><LineBreak/>
                    <Run FontSize="18" Text="Prijs excl BTW: "></Run><Run FontSize="18" Text="{Binding UnitPriceExclVAT}"></Run><LineBreak/>
                    <Run FontSize="18" Text="Marge: "></Run><Run FontSize="18" Text="{Binding Margin}"></Run>
                </TextBlock>
            </Border>
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="700,300,0,0">
            <Border>
                <TextBlock OpticalMarginAlignment="None">
                    <Run FontSize="24" Text="Extra informatie"></Run><LineBreak/>
                    <Run FontSize="18" Text="Eenheid: "></Run><Run FontSize="18" Text="{Binding UnitOfMeasure}"></Run><LineBreak/>
                    <Run FontSize="18" Text="Actuele voorraad: "></Run><Run FontSize="18" Text="{Binding ActualStock}"></Run><LineBreak/>
                    <Run FontSize="18" Text="Levertijd: "></Run><Run FontSize="18" Text="levertijd"></Run>
                </TextBlock>
            </Border>
        </StackPanel>
```

As you can see i put 2 texts behind each other. Now i want to allign the second text which start with {Bindin"} all below each other (i hope you understand what i want) Now its shown like this:

header panel 1.
Text1: binding text
longerText1: binding text
evenLongerText1: binding text

header panel 2.
Text2: binding text
longerText2: binding text
evenLongerText2: binding text

But i want this:

header panel 1.
Text1:             'binding text'
longerText1:       'binding text'
evenLongerText1:   'binding text'

header panel 2.
Text2:             'binding text'
longerText2:       'binding text'
evenLongerText2:   'binding text'

Any idea how i can accomplish my goal without just adding spaces (since that will not align nicely)?
Thanks in advance!
 Edit: oh i see it doesn't care about my enters and white spaces. let me fix that.
Edit 2: i can't fix it. and can't upload a picture (no 10 rep)
Basically i want every {binding text} to allign nicely.

Comment: show what u want as a picture form..not clear what u mean..

Comment: Hmm i can't add a picture, i don't have 10 rep. story of my life.

Comment: Agreed, it's a bit difficult to visualize what you're after. You can use one of the free temp image hosts like [imgur](https://imgur.com) and just post a link in your question until your rep raises.

Comment: I already fixed my problem ;) thanks anyhow. fixed it by using 2 stackpanels.